# Solving $X + \frac{X}{1+2} + \frac{X}{1+2+3} + \frac{X}{1+2+3+4} +\dots+ \frac{X}{1+2+3+\dots+2017} = 2017$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$$X + \frac{X}{1+2} + \frac{X}{1+2+3} + \frac{X}{1+2+3+4} +\dots+ \frac{X}{1+2+3+\dots+2017} = 2017$$

I’ve noticed that when you substitute around a bit, you get that
$yX$, where $y$ is the amount of $X$, is equal to $2017 \cdot (1+2+\dots+2017)$.
Does this actually help?

Comment: It does not help. What is the "amount of $X$"?

Comment: The amount of X is the coefficient of X if the whole left hand side of the equation is simplified to a common denominator.

Comment: Actually your right, it does not help.

Comment: The sum of reciprocals of $1, 1+2,...,1+...+2017$ can be found. Then $X$ is $2017$ divided by that sum. Is that what you want?

Comment: The answer is $2018/2=1009$. If you replace $2017$ by any natural $n$ then the answer is $(n+1)/2$.

Comment: Induction. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 10):

\begin{align*}
X &+\frac{X}{1+2}+\frac{X}{1+2+3}+\frac{X}{1+2+3+4}
+\dots+\frac{X}{1+2+3+\dots+2016+2017} \\
&= X+\frac{X}{3}+\frac{X}{6}+\frac{X}{10}
+\dots+\frac{X}{2035153} \\ 
&= 2X\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}
+\dots+\frac{1}{4070306}\right) \\ 
&= 2X\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3} 
+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot5}
+\dots+\frac{1}{2017\cdot2018}\right) \\ 
&= 2X\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} 
+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}
+\dots+\frac{1}{2017}-\frac{1}{2018}\right)
\end{align*}

By [Telescoping Series Cancellation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series),
$$
2X \left (1-\frac{1}{2018} \right) = 2017. 
$$

I hope you can proceed after this...

Answer (score 1):

We can prove the following via induction. $$ \dfrac1{1} + \dfrac1{1+2} + \dfrac1{1+2+3} + \cdots + \dfrac1{1+2+\cdots+n} = \dfrac {2n}{n+1} $$

So the solution to the equation

$$X + \frac{X}{1+2} + \frac{X}{1+2+3} + \frac{X}{1+2+3+4} +\dots+ \frac{X}{1+2+3+\cdots+n} = n$$ is $$ X = \dfrac{n+1}2 .$$